# I have a CGFloat value and I want to add another CGFloat value and display it using random numbers in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arc4random, cgfloat

I want to add two CGFloat numbers and display them using random numbers, but don't know how to do that..
My code is :

```
CGFloat latitude = 31.303702;
CGFloat longitude = 75.594905;
```

and the value I want to add to both cgfloat values is

```
CGFloat randomValue = 0.000001;
```

and display them using random numbers. Can anyone help me...
The result will be like `31.303703` & `75.594906`.

Note: The value of latitude and longitude is dynamic and its coming from an array.

Comment: How do you want to display the values?

Comment: in CGFloat. It's the latitude and longitude that I want to display.

Comment: *Display* doesn't mean very much.  Do you want to print it to the console, display it in a `UILabel`, send it to a billboard in Times Square?  Be more specific.

Comment: ask question clear. your question seems like you just want to do addition of two float values..!

Comment: yes, I want to add two float values and print it to the console...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just adding the the two and using NSLog to print on console :

```
NSLog(@"Latitude after Random Addition : %f", latitude+randomValue);
NSLog(@"Longitude after Random Addition : %f", longitude+randomValue);
```

*Update 1:*

Use following method to generate a random CGFloat between a given range:

```
- (CGFloat)randomFloatBetween:(CGFloat)smallNumber and:(CGFloat)bigNumber {
    CGFloat diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    return (((CGFloat) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;
}
```

You can call it as:

```
CGFloat randomValue1 = [self randomFloatBetween:1 and:10];
CGFloat randomValue2 = [self randomFloatBetween:3 and:5];

NSLog(@"Latitude after Random Addition : %f", latitude+randomValue1);
NSLog(@"Longitude after Random Addition : %f", longitude+randomValue2);
```

Comment: but I need more than one randomValue....
This will give me only one random value.